# DispatchGroup Not notifying 'Main" in Swift

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

I'm trying to use Dispatch group to notify me when a task is finished running. I've written a simple pseudo of what I'm trying to accomplish. For some reason my notify function gets called first.

```
    class Main {
        let cats = Cats()
        let all = ALL.singleton

        viewdidLoad(){
            cats.makeAllCall
            all.dis()
        }
    }


    class Cats {
    let dispatch = DispatchGroup()
    let all = ALL.singleton

    func makeAllCall(){
        for i in 1...10{
        all.callInfo()
        print("hello")
        }
    }
    }

    class ALL {
    static let singleton = ALL()
    let dispatch = DispatchGroup()

    func dis(){
        dispatch.notify(.main){
            print("working")
        }
    }

    func callInfo(){
        dispatch.enter()
    Alamofire.request("url", headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
            if response.result.isSuccess{
                completion(JSON(response.result.value!))
            }else{
                print("Binance - Couldn't import Request: Please check your internet connection")
            }
        }
        dispatch.leave()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not understood how dispatch groups work. You are calling `dis()`, apparently in the belief that `dispatch.notify` is something that you call. It isn't. It is called for you when every `enter` has been balanced by a `leave`. A typical structure looks like this pseudo-code:

```
let group = DispatchGroup()
// here we go...
group.enter()
_queue1_.async {
    // ... do task here ...
    group.leave()
}
group.enter()
_queue2_.async {
    // ... do task here ...
    group.leave()
}
group.enter()
_queue3_.async {
    // ... do task here ...
    group.leave()
}
// ... more as needed ...
group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
    // finished!
}
```

You need to get rid of this bizarre class structure and put everything — the dispatch group, the `enter` and `leave` calls, and the `notify` block — together in one place. If you don't want to do that, then this is not a good use of a dispatch group (perhaps what you wanted was something like Operation and OperationQueue).