# Keeping track of which uploads worked?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to upload records from Core Data to an SQL server using PHP.  Uploading one record at a time works fine, but since the uploadTask is asynchronous, I'm having trouble figuring out how to keep track of which record was successful (so I can remove it from Core Data). When I call URLSession.shared.uploadTask, I pass it a completion handler, is there anyway when that handler is called I can access the actual data record I used to call it?

```
for data in result {
    let parameters: [String: Any] = [ "date": data.value(forKey: "date") ?? -999]
    let uploadData = parameters.percentEscaped().data(using: .utf8)
    let task = URLSession.shared.uploadTask(with: urlrequest, from: uploadData) { httpdata, response, error in
            if let error = error {
                print ("error: \(error)")
                return
            }
            data.setValue(1, forKey: "toBeDeleted")
        }

        task.resume() 
}
```

The "data" object I am attempting to set in the completion block (defined outside the completion block) isn't what I think it is!

Comment: Why don't you call it each time through the loop? I mean, sure, you can use a dispatch group to wait until all the loops have finished, but why bother? What's wrong with just sending a message each time one of them is successful?

Comment: Thanks Matt  - my thought was that I need to be sure the upload was successful before I delete the local copy of that data record.  Since the completion handler doesn't have access to the actual record, how would I know which record to mark as uploaded (e.g. delete)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about the "actual record". You are saying `for data in result`. So you know what each `data` is. You yourself are saying `data.setValue(1, forKey: "toBeDeleted")`. That's the same `data`. The only thing dubious about what you're doing is that you are not getting onto the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

The `data` at the bottom of the code (if you see what I mean) is always the same as the `data` at the top of the code (in the `for` loop). The only thing I can see that you might be doing wrong is that you are saying

```
data.setValue(1, forKey: "toBeDeleted")
```

without worrying about what thread you're on. You should get onto the main thread so that you are not talking to your data on a different thread:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    data.setValue(1, forKey: "toBeDeleted")
}
```

If that doesn't work, then the problem is elsewhere, i.e. `result` does not contain the data you think it does.

(Actually I don't see why you bother setting any value of `data`. If your goal is to talk to the database and delete this object, go ahead and delete it right here, right now. Otherwise the question arises of when you will actually look for these to-be-deleted records and delete them.)

Comment: just deleting it would definitely be easier, but I had read that delete operations were exceptionally slow and I need to handle > 10 records per second.  So, I thought I'd try marking the records for deletion and then using the batch delete request.  The entire function is running on a background thread, do I need to ensure that calls within the function are also on that thread or is that just automatic?

Comment: I think I may be missing the essence of the completion handler...  If the above loop fires off 10 of those upload events, and then the completion handlers get called as each upload is processed, can I assume that the "data" from the top of the code still represents what was used when the upload task was called?

Comment: Inside the loop, yes. But there is no “completion handler” in your code so perhaps we are talking at cross purposes. I do like your idea that you might need to accumulate some things to delete before doing the deletion. Perhaps my original point about the dispatch group is germane after all? It could be used to trigger the batch deletion after the whole for loop has finished all its networking.

Comment: I really appreciate your taking the time to educate me!  I thought the block of code: ''' if let error = error '''' was the beginning of a completion block for the uploadTask call. But I also see there is another version of uploadTask that has a completion specified in the parameter list. What's the difference?  In the version of uploadTask I'm using, what is that "block" of code that I pass in with the call i.e. the {{ httpdata, response, error in...

Comment: Oh I see, _that_ completion handler. Yes, but if you want to coordinate information back to the code that that called `resume` to begin with, you need your _own_ completion handler. Maybe you'd better read up on asynchronous code: http://www.programmingios.net/what-asynchronous-means/ And as I say, if you want to accumulate the results before doing anything, you will also need a dispatch group: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52378369/dispatchgroup-not-notifying-main-in-swift/52378389#52378389